# Safe to assume pyspark's subtract on a rdd is slow / problematic?

Tags: pyspark

While running a pyspark job and as the input grows, I notice that I keep getting memory errors like the following...

```
ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 12 on compute-2-10.local:
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB
physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

While it will successfully complete on a smaller input even when the error is repeated through execution, it eventually dies as the input size increases.

I have ~20,000,000 million rows that I need to filter out ~661,000 rows from that.  I can't think of any other way of dealing with this besides using subtract given the format of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.5GB is very low for executor memory: typically try to give at least twice that amount. This problem should likely be resolved just by not starving the executor of resources.

Comment: Ok yeah I figured.  I don't actually have access to the servers to be able to change it but I have reached out to the admins to see what they can do about the error.  Won't likely hear back till Monday

Comment: I was able to set it to use more memory and it worked.  Still a bit slow but it doesn't fail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use at least 4gb of memory. You can set it like this:
pyspark --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 4g